# How do I create separate pull request for each commit on git?

Tags: git, github

I am working on project where, whenever I push my code to GitHub I need to create separate pull request for each new feature.

I am using `git flow feature` (Git flow and hotfix) function to create feature branch for each new feature I am working on. But, if my pervious pull request (Previous topics feature) has not been merged, I don't know how to make another pull request so I don't merge my previous feature branch's code to new feature branch's code. Can someone guide me how do I make separate pull request for each new feature ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're branching off of feature branches that haven't yet been merged.

If you have, for example, a master branch plus one branch per feature, you should be branching the new features off of master, not whatever feature you're currently working on, that way the new code will be separate.

Here is an example of how you might work on a new feature:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b feature_name
(implement some stuff on this branch)
git add (files added)
git commit -m "describe the feature you added"
git push --set-upstream origin feature_name
```

Then go on github to open to pull request to merge feature_name to master.

Comment: I am branching off from my master branch.  This what I am doing: `git flow feature start hello-world`. I develop my feature then I do, `git flow feature publish hello-world`. Then I go to GitHub and create pull request to master repo. After that, `git checkout master`. Once I do that I go and create new feature branch. As soon as I am done. I do the same thing as above.

Comment: If you branch off of master, the code for unmerged features won't be present in the new branch. Perhaps I don't understand the problem? Once you've created the new branch it's unnecessary to merge from other feature branches, just merge each of them into master once ready and fix any merge conflicts.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Is there any other way to commit my code to github ? Without using `git flow feature`

Comment: If you have github set as the remote origin, just commit your code to the branch (say it's called feature_branch) then call `git push --set-upstream origin feature_branch`

Answer (score 0):

After committing on one feature branch, run

```
git checkout master
```

before creating your new feature branch. This will make sure you *branch* off of master instead of from the another feature branch.

Comment: Yeah, I might be doing something wrong. Checking it now. Thank you for your reply.